# Waiting for messages in Managed Code

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi, message-queue

This is closely related to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419776/modal-operation-using-imessagefilter-and-doevents).

In the managed world:

- How do I check if the current thread
  has messages in its message queue?
- How do I yield to the OS and wait
  for a message in the current thread
  (like GetMessage or WaitMessage)?

I am looking for the managed equivalents without PInvoke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [AddMessageFilter function.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx)

I don't think there's a blocking way how to do that without P/Invoke, since it's beyond intentions of .NET.

Comment: Why should waiting for a message violate the design principles of .NET? Just curious. In what way is it harmful?

Comment: Not exactly violate, you can still do it, that's why there's stuff like P/Invoke. Maybe I should have written Windows Forms, but the point remains unchanged.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that AddMessageFilter does not "check if the current thread has messages" nor does it "wait for a message in the current thread" as required by my post.

Comment: However, I must accept this as the answer since it's the one that gets closest to what I want to do.

Answer (score 3):

You could override WndProc and then fire your own event when it gets called. This, of course, wouldn't be blocking. If you want to block until a message, you could have a method in another thread waiting on a synchronisation object and have the WndProc signal that object.

Comment: This looks like the best bet I totally missed the question thought you were looking to pump the message queue;-)

Comment: Which WndProc would you override?  Every control has its own.